# Where is x-content-type-options: nosniff coming from?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I am using express 4.x with node 4.4.3. The web server is nginx and I am running a http server module in node - for which I am using nginx as a reverse proxy (using 'upstream'). I see the below response header when I inspect it in browser console

```
x-content-type-options: nosniff
```

I have thoroughly checked my nginx conf file for this setting / header but it isn't there. Wonder if I could get some pointers as to where it might be coming from? And when I add `add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;` in nginx.conf then I see the above appear twice in the reponse headers as shown below

```
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
```

Wonder what's causing this. Please let me know if any further information is needed. Thanks

Here's my node installed modules folder contents

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably coming from a package installed in your express application. You should check the `package.json` file. Look for the `dependencies` part listing all the packages installed.

[Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet) is typically one of the packages adding the `X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff` header.

Edit: according to your list of dependencies the most probable solution is that you return 'jsonp' content with Express. In this case Express will add the `X-Content-Type-Options` header when no `Content-Type` header is set by the user (see the response.js file at line 289 in node_modules/express/lib).
It could also come from one or another dependency used by Express like 'finalhandler', 'send' or 'serve-static' (see [there](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/package.json) for Express' dependencies list) but it is hard to be sure without debugging your whole application.

Comment: oh thanks for the clue but my node installation is pretty new and I haven't installed Helmet. Here's my 'require' list that I use in my application

var moment = require('moment');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

Thanks

Comment: OK. Do you mind posting also the dependencies list of package.json?

Comment: Node and express are pretty new to me. I wonder what is the location of package.json as I cannot find it under node installation, nor the application directory. Let me add a screenshot of my installed modules to the original post. Thanks

Comment: You should find this file at the root of your project, it is standard for a node app. You should get it when doing a `npm init`. Then when you add all your dependencies with `npm install --save name_of_the_dependency` the file will describe all the packages installed in the node_modules folder. 
Concerning your dependencies it am not sure which package add the header. It could come from Express directly which inject the header in case of a jsonp response when there is no Content-Type set by the user. I will update the answer, but you will surely have to investigate :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointers. Apparently it's coming from express as I got the clue from another question that I had posted on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178175/node-express-app-returns-text-javascript-response-header-content-type-in-spit/37179056#37179056

Here's the post for reference and the link to express where is shows the Content-Type settings: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/12bc16e72fe34ce7e3658679b694e47dce56ae7a/lib/response.js#L298-L302

I will take this up on github with the devs. And I will mark yours as the answers as it pretty much says the same.

Comment: Glad you found the source, that was the file I spoke about in my answer :)